# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72

Tags: flutter, gradle

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:27.1.0

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe a temporary problem or you have to add mvnCentral() to your gradle repositories definition in your build file - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.72  contains the artifact.

Comment: can u try to remove the build folder and rerun the app? Also please share `build.gradle` file

Comment: Can you talk on discord ? the code is above